# Two Android modules with the same applicationId and package name in project

Tags: android, gradle, manifest, sign

I have app on Google Play. And i used the same project for android tv box. Because of this i had to change manifest and gradle before signing apk and publishing. I decided to create different modules in app. I have core library and two modules. 
1.Phone app module
2.TV Box module

But now i having problem with package name. I need to use the same application id in two apks. Any solutions? Android studio does'nt allow me to have the same module names. When i change applicationId in gradle. I'm having

```
Error:The generated mypackagename.R class cannot be found
```

I need the same applicationId's because in Android Boxes i have custome firmware which launches my app by default and i can't change applicationId in Play Store too.

Comment: Solution is using different module names, but same application id.

Comment: solution is use flavor feature for create two app with same package name.

Comment: @NorthernPoet I have different modules. But as i mentioned i'm getting Error:The generated mypackagename.R class cannot be found

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for this case by myself

removed applicationId in gradle files
renamed package in folder. So my modules have the same package
changed package name in manifest

So now i have two modules  which use core library. 
Both modules has the same packages and the same package names in manifest

Comment: does your app doesn't have a `BuildConfig` conflict? If you are using kotlin, I suggest you to use `import aliasing`, e.g: `import yourpackage.a as A` & `import yourpackage.b as B`, so it is safe to use different package name to avoid conflict with same package name